# Unable to get Multistore working correctly on Prestashop ( Windows ) 1.7 for second store

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So - pretty stock standard installation.  All I am trying to do is add a second store and make it work like the first one.  My steps are: ( just using the default theme )

1. install Bitnami windows installer
2. Enable Multi store
3. Create a new Shop
4. Point a couple of domains to the IP address of the store using hosts wile on windows
5. Set the URL's of each shop to the same urls

It appears to work - but when I go to the second ( newly created ) store, the layout looks correct and the images of the theme are there - but none of the categories goes to proper pages and none of the product images apprear to be there

I have also disabled caching and tried adding a new product with all shops selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating **.htaccess** file from **SEO&URL** menu
(saving the configuration on that page should do the trick).

If this does not help check your **ps_shop_url** database table and make sure all details are OK (make sure that physical_url is "/" for all shops if you have configured multishop on top level domains).

If you still have troubles and need multishop for testing purposes, just use a subfolder like "**/shop2**" for your second shop as it will be surely easier to setup.

Comment: None of those worked - but the physical directory by defauly is "prestashop" ..?